# Why php artisan migrate fails: undefined method?

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, command-prompt, laravel-5.3

Look this image : https://postimg.org/image/4fvu34juz/

When I run php artisan migrate, there is display :

```
[symfony\component\debug\exception\fatalthrowableerror]
call to undefined method illuminate\database\schema\blueprint::textarea<>
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

**Update :**

Code :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFlightTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
        Schema::drop('flights');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the migration please.

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin, I had update my question

Comment: error says that you're trying to use `textarea` somewhere, so you should find this migration and show it to us.

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin, Solved. I find it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there is no function named `textarea()` in class `Blueprint`. Remove code that call it.

Comment: Your migration looks ok, maybe there is somewhere in your code (another migration script?) that calls textarea(). Maybe what you need is `text()` method.

Comment: Solved. I find it. Thank you